# jdk- 15.0.1_windows-x64_bin.exe not Opening

Tags: java, windows, java-15

Quick One.. I downloaded  jdk- 15.0.1_windows-x64_bin.exe from oracle's official website and tried running it on my PC but it doesn't work. Ive tried running it as administrator but still to no avail.. **When launched the app opens up in the task manager and then after some seconds it closes.**

My PC Spec is :

Microsoft Windows 10
Version 10.0.10240
HP 250 G1 notebook PC
x64-based pc

Please I am very frustrated. I need jdk to install netbeans 12.2. I already have jre 8 installed

Comment: You can try a JDK from [AdoptOpenJDK](https://adoptopenjdk.net/).

Comment: OR Amazon Correto:https://docs.aws.amazon.com/corretto/latest/corretto-15-ug/downloads-list.html

Comment: It sounds like maybe the download was incomplete or corrupted. The first thing I would try is downloading it again. I think Oracle also provides a checksum you could use to validate the download.

Comment: Please only add tags that are directly relevant to the issue/question. This has nothing to do with PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I've just found out the solution.. I updated my jre with jre-8u271-windows-x64.exe..

And deleted all other jre including outdated upadates installed and it worked perfectly fine..

Hope this works for you